# Converting comma-separated value to in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have following query :

```
Set @OrderStatuses = 'Cancelled,Complete'  

Select * 
From TableName  
Where Status in (@OrderStatuses)
```

The `Status` is what I am receiving externally and it fails to fetch any result as, what we actually need to process is:

```
Select * 
From TableName  
Where Status in ('Cancelled', 'Complete');
```

`@OrderStatuses` can contain any number of comma-separated values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'Select * from TableName Where Status in (@list)';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@list', '@OrderStatuses');

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note:  You cannot pass a list in as a parameter.

You can also use `like`:

```
Select *
from TableName
Where ',' + @OrderStatuses + ',' like '%,' + Status + ',%';
```

However, this cannot use an index for the the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use [split string function](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) and process the rest..

```
;with cte
as
(
select * from split_strings(@orderstatus,',')
)
select * from table where status in (select item from cte)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add the list as a [Table-Valued Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Here are two methods I use to convert any IEnumerable list of items (in this case, integers) into a *Table Valued Parameter*. You have to have created/defined a User Defined type (UDT) for the resultant table in your database. In the example below the UDT is named `dbo.keyIds` and is created (once) with this SQL:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[KeyIds] 
AS TABLE(pkId int NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   ( [pkId] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
 )
```

The c# code is:

```
public class DbParamList : List<IDbDataParameter>
{ 
    public void AddSQLTableParm<T>(
                string parmName, IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        var parm = new SqlParameter(parmName, CreateDataTable(values))
        {
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
            TypeName = "dbo.keyIds"
        };
        Add(parm);
    }
    internal static DataTable CreateDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        var props = typeof (T).GetProperties();
        if (props.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var col in props)
                dt.Columns.Add(col.Name, col.PropertyType);
            foreach (var id in values)
            {
                var newRow = dt.NewRow();
                foreach (var prop in id.GetType().GetProperties())
                    newRow[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(id, null);
                dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("ids");
            foreach (var id in values) dt.Rows.Add(id);
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```